# How to change naming conventions in large bodies of existing code?

Tags: c#, c++, naming-conventions, renaming

I need to change an existing code base from naming convention X to something like Camel Case.

It's in Visual Studio 2008.  A couple of hundred thousand lines of code. Some of it is C#. Some of it is unmanaged C++.

I started to re-factor this manually.  But, it's pretty mechanical.  I was thinking that a product could do in seconds what's going to take me weeks by hand.

The customer is pretty finicky about their own naming conventions.  So, if I use a product, it has to be customizable to their standard.

I'm even thinking of writing a Visual Studio add-in to do it.

Anyone know of any products that might work for this?
I don't really care if it runs inside Visual Studio or not.

Thanks!

Comment: given a symbol x can you extract it's camel case convention?

Comment: How much are you getting paid for this?  Aim higher.

Comment: My answer would be, "don't."  "Don't sweat the small stuff." - Sutter

Comment: consider `under_scores` instead of `camelCase`, it's easier to read

Answer (score 1):

I know there are several renaming tools based on lexical/semantic analysis, but I don't think there is a conversion tool available for your specific "naming convention X."

Although writing a VS add-on is not a bad idea, I'd recommend you to write a script in your favorite scripting language. (such as Perl, Python, Ruby, or whatever)

Comment: Check out Visual Assist X. It comes with pretty nice renaming feature. It's commercial though. http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/rename.asp

Answer (score 0):

[ReSharper's renaming refactoring](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Rename):

> The Rename refactoring allows you to rename any symbol, including: namespaces, types, methods, parameters, local variables, properties, fields, and events. It automatically finds and corrects all references to the symbol. The Rename refactoring can be invoked directly from the editor and sometimes from other views (Class View, Object Browser).
>
> Rename works with all supported languages and technologies - namely, C#, VB.NET, ASP.NET, XML, XAML, and build scripts.
>
> Automatic reference correction fully extends to XAML markup when you use the Rename refactoring. In addition, specific XAML symbols such as namespace aliases and resources can be renamed easily:

It can also detect variables that do not conform to your specified naming conventions.

I'm not sure how well it integrates with managed C++, but once you start using ReSharper with C#, you'll wonder how you ever lived without it.

Comment: Thanks, but not my situation.